# Jquerymobile Page Redirecting with URL through PHP?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

Here i have a problem with redirecting the URL with PHP Form submit the page is Changing But the URL is not Changing.......

Here is the Code:

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
 <input type="text" id="emp" name="emp" />
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form> 

<?php
 $name =$_POST['name'];
 if($name != '')
{
  header("Location :sample.php");
}
else
{
  header("Location :index.php");
}
?>
```

But It is Redirecting and the url is not changing it is displaying like `http:localhost/sample/addForm.php#/sample/insert.php` actually i want it like `http:localhost/sample/sample.php` or `http:localhost/sample/index.php`

Comment: Missing domain ! Change the call functions to be header("Location: /sample/sample.php"); And header("Location: /sample/index.php");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
if($name != '')
{
  header("Location: /sample/sample.php");
}
else
{
  header("Location: /sample/index.php");
}
```